# Bcrypt_lib.node: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bcrypt

I'm running an instance with this particular version `Node.js 14 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.6.0`, before it was running fine when it is on version `5.5.6`, what is weird is I haven't had any change on package.json, which gives me an error of something like below

```
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: Error: /var/app/current/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/dist/modules/mongodb/user.repository.js:18:18)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32) {
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
Oct 13 06:02:07 ip-172-18-7-7 web: }
```

I also `unsafe-perm=true` already on `.npmrc`, this seemed to be not working now :(
thanks in advance for the help!